# Replacing 23 year old 190 limiter for ceiling fan

Tags: electrical

I have a 23 year old Harbor Breeze ceiling fan. The 190 limiter burnt out.
Removed the limiter which has just two blue wires coming from it. Limiter was made in China.

Can only find a replacement limiter with 3 wires (Blue, Red, White). Can I assume that the white wire is the ground wire and what in the fan can I ground it to?

Comment: What is a "190 limiter"?  A photo may be helpful.

Comment: @jwh20  Great question!, one of your best..lol

Comment: It's a thermal cutout, an overload protective device. It prevents you from putting in lamps with too high of a wattage and damaging the fixture.. Did you just attempt to put in bigger lamps? If so, remove them and see if it resets.

Comment: Can't you just remove the burnt out limiter and wire straight to the lamp? A professional electrician is legally prohibited from doing this, but it is not illegal for a homeowner to do so. One fan installation company told me they remove this when installing light kits because the limiters fail so often. Is the limiter in the light kit or in the fan wiring? I installed several fans in a relative's house and left the wiring as received. We had two new Hunters installed and if and when the limiter fails I would consider doing without it.

Comment: I was told that the motivation for the legal requirement for the limiter was energy savings rather than safety. But I appreciate the risk of overloading the small diameter wires supplying the light fixture.

Comment: Is the limiter in the light kit or in the fan?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JRaef the limiters were mandated by law and many fans were tossed when they failed, I know my personal fans do not have them a wire nut must have been installed by some gremlins or friendly elves In the night. The ones I have replaced red is hot white neutral black to the lamp and the lamp back to white.  There also ones that black and red are reversed so your particular model of limiter is needed to be sure. Whoops yours had blue and not black so the model will be needed to be sure. Wilt LED lamps they really are not needed , but prevent someone from putting in more wattage than the fixture is rated for.

Edit I did find one that was red input blue output and white neutral similar to the first one I listed but the part number should be checked because I have got them that the input and output were swapped